# Convert MultiIndex Names to DataFrame Column Values & Rename DataFrame Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have below Dataframe with MultiIndex columns, need to prepare regular dataframe

df:

```
Instrument PDKRW1M
Field           ER
Date              
2019-02-28  1124.0
2019-03-01  1125.5
2019-03-04  1126.0
2019-03-05  1126.5
2019-03-06  1127.0
2019-03-07  1132.0
2019-03-08  1133.5
2019-03-11  1133.0
2019-03-12  1128.0
2019-03-13  1129.5
2019-03-14  1135.0
```

df.columns:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['PDKRW1M'], ['ER']],
       labels=[[0], [0]],
       names=['Instrument', 'Field'])
```

Want to prepare dataframe like this:

```
Date    Value   Instrument  Field
2019-02-28  1124.0  PDKRW1M ER
2019-03-01  1125.5  PDKRW1M ER
2019-03-04  1126.0  PDKRW1M ER
2019-03-05  1126.5  PDKRW1M ER
2019-03-06  1127.0  PDKRW1M ER
2019-03-07  1132.0  PDKRW1M ER
2019-03-08  1133.5  PDKRW1M ER
2019-03-11  1133.0  PDKRW1M ER
2019-03-12  1128.0  PDKRW1M ER
2019-03-13  1129.5  PDKRW1M ER
2019-03-14  1135.0  PDKRW1M ER
2019-03-14  1135.0  PDKRW1M ER
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with first and second level for `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df = df.unstack().reset_index(level=[0,1], name='Value')
#for column Date
#df = df.unstack().reset_index(name='Value')
print (df)
           Instrument Field   Value
Date                               
2019-02-28    PDKRW1M    ER  1124.0
2019-03-01    PDKRW1M    ER  1125.5
2019-03-04    PDKRW1M    ER  1126.0
2019-03-05    PDKRW1M    ER  1126.5
2019-03-06    PDKRW1M    ER  1127.0
2019-03-07    PDKRW1M    ER  1132.0
2019-03-08    PDKRW1M    ER  1133.5
2019-03-11    PDKRW1M    ER  1133.0
2019-03-12    PDKRW1M    ER  1128.0
2019-03-13    PDKRW1M    ER  1129.5
2019-03-14    PDKRW1M    ER  1135.0
```

If necessary change order of columns:

```
df = df[df.columns[-1:].tolist() + df.columns[:-1].tolist()]
#for column Date
#df = df[df.columns[-2:].tolist() + df.columns[:-2].tolist()]
print (df)
             Value Instrument Field
Date                               
2019-02-28  1124.0    PDKRW1M    ER
2019-03-01  1125.5    PDKRW1M    ER
2019-03-04  1126.0    PDKRW1M    ER
2019-03-05  1126.5    PDKRW1M    ER
2019-03-06  1127.0    PDKRW1M    ER
2019-03-07  1132.0    PDKRW1M    ER
2019-03-08  1133.5    PDKRW1M    ER
2019-03-11  1133.0    PDKRW1M    ER
2019-03-12  1128.0    PDKRW1M    ER
2019-03-13  1129.5    PDKRW1M    ER
2019-03-14  1135.0    PDKRW1M    ER
```